# Default Radio button not visually checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm building a dynamic list of `RadioButton` inside a `For` loop 
using

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, m.Value) %>
```

The dynamic list gets created alright but the first `RadioButton` is **NOT VISUALLY checked**

What I mean by this is that the circle portion of the `RadioButton` is not filled with the black dot that tells you it's checked.

However, when I inspect the HTML in the browser's dev tools, the attribute checked="checked" is set!

I tried doing a JQUERY onload

```
$("#yada").attr("checked", "checked");

$("#yada").click();
```

and NOTHING works!!!  The inspector still says the element checked: true but still the little circle does not get the black dot in it UNLESS I manually click it.

I've also tried setting the first radio button like

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Gender, m.Value, new { checked = "checked"})
```

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery selector is correct?  I've had to do something similar on document.ready() clicking the first in a radio button list.

Comment: if you know ahead of time which radio button to check (in your case it looks like the first one), can you just add the checked attribute directly in asp.net like so: `Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Gender, m.Value, new { checked = "checked"})`. Also, not sure if this was just a typo on your part, but the jquery for modifiying an attribute is attr(), not attrs()

Comment: @Kolichikov yea it was a typo sorry like I said the element in the inspector shows the attribute checked is there and set to true...also tried to specifically set checked = "checked" inside the lamba expresison

Comment: @Seano666 yup all corrrect in the debugger the element is grabbed correctly and I can see that the checked attribute is true

Comment: Is there another element in that collection of radio buttons that also has checked set? Do you have any other radio button lists on the page that might be using the same radio button category?

Comment: @Kolichikov no nothing like that let me post some images so that you guys can see

Comment: Are RadioButtons in a table?

Comment: @Kolichikov hey man thanks for bringing that up apparently there was more than 1 list being created so yes I had more radio buttons on the page I just could not see them but that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give an answer to this question for anyone who encounters a similar issue (without reading the comments):

If you manually set `checked` to multiple elements in the same radio button group (defined by the `name` attribute), only the last one will be displayed as checked, but once you click on one manually, it will reset all the checked elements to match your latest selection.
See this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/0ekaznbb/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you tested code in Google Chrome. You should edit parent elements for solve this problem.
Please see `[https://jsfiddle.net/rcet5btw/][1]`